# Growth of direct products

Tags: group-theory, geometric-group-theory, infinite-groups

Let $G$ and $H$ be finitely generated groups. Is it true that $ \gamma_{G \times H} $ is weakly equivalent to $ \gamma_{G}\gamma_{H} $?

Assuming the answer is yes, can one use exactly the same proof as in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/241209/growth-in-direct-product?rq=1) post? (If $S$ and $T$ are the sets of generators of $G$ and $H$, I take $S\times 1 \cup 1 \times T$ as a generating set for $G \times H$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, since
$$
\gamma_{G\times H}(r) \;\leq\; \gamma_G(r)\, \gamma_H(r)
$$
and
$$
\gamma_G(r)\,\gamma_H(r) \;\leq\; \gamma_{G\times H}(2r).
$$